# HTMLUnit how to check if proxy is working properly

Tags: proxy, error-handling, htmlunit

Do you know what can I do to check if proxy in WebBrowser is working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Well, if the proxy does not exist, you will have an error:

   ```
   WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_8, "localhost", 8080);
   HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sf.net");
   System.out.println(page.asText());
   ```

> ```
> org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException:
> ```
>
> Connection to http://localhost:8080
>   refused
>         at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:127)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:147)

2. If the proxy misbehaves, you will have a different page than what you expected

Comment: Can I catch it by try and catch ?